Implementing a navigatable TabSheet
I am trying to extends the Tabsheet class of vaadin to a reusable component to support navigation. Each tab has a certain url target.
I am stucking on getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.navigate(navigationTarget, target)). This is not supported by the method, what do I have to change, that I can give a class name to the component that navigate works?
public class NavigateableTabSheet<T> extends TabSheet {

 private Map<String, Tab> tabs;

 public NavigateableTabSheet(Class<? extends C> navigationTarget) {
     this.tabs = new HashMap<String, Tab>();

     this.addSelectedChangeListener(l  -> {
         // Get the navigation Target
         String target = tabs.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(getSelectedTab())).findFirst().map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse("");

         if(target != null) {
             getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.navigate(navigationTarget, target));
         }
     });
 }

 public void add(Tab tab, Component component, String navigationTarget) {
     this.tabs.put(navigationTarget, tab);
     this.add(tab, component);
 }

 @Override
 public void remove(Tab tab) {
     String key = "";
     for(HashMap.Entry<String, Tab> entry : tabs.entrySet()) {
         if(entry.getValue().equals(tab)) {
             key = entry.getKey();
             break;
         }
     }
     tabs.remove(key);
     super.remove(tab);
 }
}

I do not know how to write the constructor the right way. Can someone give me a hint?

The UI.navigate(..) method only accepts classes that extend Component. So you need to use Class<? extends Component> navigationTarget as your parameter(s).  The ? extends Component means any class that inherits from the Component class is acceptable.
It sounds like TabSheet may not be the correct component to use for this case (see the note at the bottom of my post), however, I'll update your code to provide something that works and helps show the generic class parameters.
public static class NavigateableTabSheet extends TabSheet {

    private Map<Tab, Class<? extends Component>> tabs;

    public NavigateableTabSheet() {

        this.tabs = new HashMap<>();

        // Try to navigate when tab is changed
        this.addSelectedChangeListener(l -> {

            // Verify a tab is selected
            if (l.getSelectedTab() == null) {
                return;
            }

            // Get the navigation Target
            Class<? extends Component> target = tabs.get(l.getSelectedTab());

            if (target != null) {
                getUI().ifPresent(ui -> ui.navigate(target));
            }
        });
    }

    public void add(Tab tab, Component component, Class<? extends Component> navigationTarget) {
        this.tabs.put(tab, navigationTarget);
        this.add(tab, component);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(Tab tab) {
        tabs.remove(tab);
        super.remove(tab);
    }

}

Note on navigation and TabSheet:
The TabSheet component is made for switching between content without navigating. If actual navigation (changing between views) is your intention, there are more standard ways to achieve this.
I would recommend taking a look at the AppLayout component and look at examples in the docs. This component has dedicated areas for navigation menu and a "content" area that is updated when navigation occurs. If you like the look of the tabs, you can still use The Tab and Tabs components (not the TabSheet component). You can also use normal Anchor components, or even the easy SidebarNav component.
